# javascript url call working randomly

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function which I am calling from php code. The function is not working if the argument passed is text; it works fine for integer argument. There is probably some very basic issue I am missing. Please point that out.

```
function make_entry(game)
    {
        window.location.href="generate.php?game="+game;
    }

<? echo "<div style='text-align:center'>Click <a onclick='make_entry(".$game.")' style='cursor:pointer'><b>Here</b></a> to download your Certificate.</div>"; ?>
```

php code is fine in my humble opinion

Comment: And what does the text that you set as `$game` look like

Comment: as simple as $game = "excel";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes around your `$game` variable if the argument is to be passed as text.

```
<?php echo "<div style='text-align:center'>Click <a onclick=\"make_entry('$game')\" style='cursor:pointer'><b>Here</b></a> to download your Certificate.</div>"; ?>
```

See fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rq9-x8e

Comment: please suggest a way by which it is compatible for both integer as well as string arguments

Comment: Why not pass all as a string? Your javascript in the `make_entry` function you have provided will infer it as a string anyway when you concatenate and won't care either way.

Answer (score 0):

you have to place the content of `$game` between quotes in order to work with a string

```
onclick='make_entry("\".$game.\"")'
```

keep in mind, of course, that this way you'll be alway passing a string to the function.

And `$game` **must not** contain double quotes or again the JavaScript code will fail.

Just consider your JavaScript code when the content of the variable is actually put in place.

Comment: i want a code compatible for both integer and string arguments ... please suggest if there is a way for that

Comment: I think the second \ should be after the first double quote not before it.

Comment: @AakashGoel the code will do work with both number and strings. But your javascript `make_entry` will always receive a string (either containing text like `"excel"` or a number like `"610"`. This shouldn't be an issue unless `make_entry` explicitly checks the type passed and behaves differently with numbers and strings

Answer (score -2):

`<? echo` should be `<?php echo`

Comment: Not if short-tags is on.